# System.Net.WebException Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. failing on social media calls

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, c#-4.0, twitter, webrequest

we are using facebook graph API,Spring.Social.Twitter API for retrieving Contacts all the social media calls are failing from our web application, from all API calls we are getting a same Exception.

**Twitter API GetResponse**

```
Exception Type: System.Net.WebException
Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
StackTrace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Inner Exception ---------------------------------------------------
Type: System.IO.IOException
Exception: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
StackTrace:    at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
```

**Facebook Graph API Call**

this is the stack trace for graph API call get response

```
Exception Type: Facebook.WebExceptionWrapper
Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
StackTrace:    at Facebook.HttpHelper.OpenRead()
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)

Inner Exception ---------------------------------------------------
Type: System.IO.IOException
Exception: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
StackTrace:    at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
```

this is the stack trace for all the API calls.
thanks in advance.

**Note: if am Editing My Web config,Everything starts working Fine for some hours.after that same error for all the get request.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by removing the following line from making the Rest Service Calls

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

once this `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` has set in your Application to SSL3 this will be applied for the whole Aplication.
after this all the Https calls will be using SSL3 for making Request.and the request made will give us the Above Error

After the declaration of vulnerablity of SSL3 protocol Facebook,LinkedIn,= and Twitter may have removed the support of SSL3.
 here is the more details regarding SSL3 Poodle https://scotthelme.co.uk/sslv3-goes-to-the-dogs-poodle-kills-off-protocol/